# How to generate tables from ddl - SQL Data Modeler to SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, ddl

I have generated a ddl file with the SQL Data Modeller tool. However, when I try to import the ddl script, it executes but there aren't any   tables under the tree node view (except the system ones, because I am logged in as the `sys` user)? Does this mean that they were not  created (generated by the script) at all?

Comment: Don't do that - leave SYS alone. Create another user and do whatever you're doing there. As of your question: no idea, I don't use that.

Comment: This kind of question may be better suited at https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Create a new user -this will be the schema for your objects.

You can do this in your model - create the user in your physical model, then assign that schema for all of your objects

[I show how to do this in DETAIL with lots of pictures here.](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2018/10/data-modeler-tip-assigning-a-schema-to-your-objects/)

When you generate the DDL, it should create the user and then each object CREATE statement will have the USER.OBJECT_NAME notation.

[image]

You could run this script as SYS.

Your other option is to create a new user, login as that user, and then run your scripts.

But don't ever ever create objects in SYS or the SYSTEM accounts.